# How to use bold html tag in ireport 4.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I'm using some html tags in my text to generate a pdf with Ireport 4.5.0.

On the textfield I checked Markup with HTML so, when I use `<b>` or `<strong>` doesn't work in my pdf. My **words** doesn't appear in **bold**....with underline works fine...

What I missing?

I thought just put **markup html** my pdf will work but it's not going on right way.

Sorry my english!

Comment: Did you try another markups? Did you try another formats (rtf, for example)? Does it work in iReport preview mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried another markups and still doesn't working bold tags. I didn't try in preview.

Comment: This one works well: `<textField>
    <reportElement x="206" y="41" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Bold</b> text"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>` with JasperReports 5.6 (iReport 5.6.0)

Comment: Did you check bold text without markup? Maybe it is a font issue...

Comment: I'll try with your code, maybe I need to update my jasperreports...In pdf to put in bold, I use  helvetica-bold in pdf font name (deprecated) and works fine, but I don't use helvetica-bold because is not always that I want bold text. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: On preview works fine, but when I export to pdf, doesn't work "<b> </b>"

Comment: Try to use 5.6+ version of JasperReports or/and another font